# compile package is not loaded in chez scheme

Tags: emacs, compilation, scheme, read-eval-print-loop, chez-scheme

I have installed petite chez scheme and used a .el config file as follows- my .emacs file:

```
    (add-to-list 'load-path "/home/lambda/slime-2013-04-05")  ; your SLIME directory
    (setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/bin/clisp") ; your Lisp system
    (require 'slime)
    (slime-setup)
    (setq slime-protocol-version 'ignore) 

    ;;petite scheme setup
    (setq scheme-program-name "/home/lambda/csv8.4/custom/petite")
    (load-file                "/home/lambda/.emacs.d/scheme-setup.el")


(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)))


(if (fboundp 'global-font-lock-mode)
    (global-font-lock-mode 1)        ; GNU Emacs
  (setq font-lock-auto-fontify t))   ; XEmacs
```

and the scheme-setup.el file I'm using is here:

https://github.com/tiljeset/emacs/blob/master/scheme-setup.el

Now, when I do

```
$ emacs -nw -f run-scheme
```

and compile with `C-c C-k`, I get the error:

```
Exception in compile-file: compile package is not loaded
Type (debug) to enter the debugger.
```

in the REPL. May I ask what is causing this problem?

```
(compile-file filename.ss)
```

gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to buy the compile package. Instructions at [www.scheme.com](http://www.scheme.com).

Comment: Yes. As in money. I'm not sure what the current pricing is, but there is an educational discount available, and it's not too expensive. That's the only way to get the compiler for full Chez Scheme. Otherwise you can just use the interpreter Petite Chez Scheme. You need full Chez Scheme for the C function interface, and if you want to distribute pre-compiled binaries without source code. Otherwise the interpreter works just fine; in particular, once a program starts up, there is no difference in speed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer- C-c C-l must suffice for now- when compilation is require I'll use DrRacket!

Comment: This is an old question but the full Chez Scheme is now open sourced at https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/